# how to use the value of data within an multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello my first question ever on stackoverflow. Im quite new in jquery and js. ill try to be specific as possible.

I've made an object within another object. Ive tried to make a list of people(object) with different fishes(object) they own. the people object went very well, but the object fishes didn't work out. Now in the datasource file i have made 2 arrays. one for people one for fish.

as followed:

```
var data = 
[

    {
        "id": 1,
        "guid": "14f09c11-d343-44a6-a8b5-ddfc9196636f",
        "isActive": true,
        "age": 27,
        "name": "Abe",
        "fishes" : 0

    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "guid": "3129a7d7-c956-4201-bda4-338d27e15fdf",
        "isActive": true,
        "age": 39,
        "name": "Rachel",
        "fishes":1

    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "guid": "c4dea911-9523-4fdc-b129-f2ba10b40a8d",
        "isActive": true,
        "age": 20,
        "name": "harrison",
         "fishes":2


    }

]

var datafish = 
[
{
    "id":1,
    "name": "gruber",
    "color": "red",
    "edible": true,
    "picture":"fish1.jpg"

},
{
    "id":2,
    "name": "dorade",
    "color": "green",
    "edible": true,
    "picture":"fish2.jpg"

},
{
    "id":3,
    "name": "puff-fish",
    "color": "random",
    "edible": false,
    "picture":"fish3.jpeg"

}
]
```

As you can see each person owns a fish ( under fishes). Now i want in jquery or js to show only the fish they own in their profile. i just don't know how to reference to the fishes value in var data . And thats exactly what i need...

i have tried this in my js file:

```
 var i = data[fishes.value];
```

And:

```
 var i = data.fishes.value;
```

I hope you guys understand my question, if not ill happily provide more information.

Thank you!

Edit:

ill add my functions as well:

```
function create(persona)
{
var body = $('body');
var person = $('<div></div>').addClass('person').appendTo(body);
var name = $('<div></div>').addClass('name').appendTo(person);
var img = $('<img/>').appendTo(person);
var age = $('<div></div>').addClass('age').appendTo(person);
name.text(persona.name);
age.text(persona.age);
img.attr('src', 'graphics/' + persona.picture);
fish();



}   

function fish()
{
var body = $('body');
    var person = $('<div></div>').addClass('person').appendTo(body);
    var fishbar = $('<div></div>').addClass('fishbar').appendTo(person);

 var i = data[fishes.value]

    var fishmenu = $('<div></div>').addClass('fishmenu').appendTo(fishbar);
    var fishimg = $('<img/>').addClass('fishpicture').appendTo(fishmenu);
    var fishcolor = $('<div></div>').addClass('fishcolor').appendTo(fishmenu);
    var fishedible = $('<div></div>').addClass('fishedible').appendTo(fishmenu);
    var fishname = $('<div></div>').addClass('fishname').appendTo(fishmenu);

    fishimg.attr('src', 'graphics/' + datafish[i].picture);
    fishname.text(datafish[i].name);
    fishcolor.text(datafish[i].color);
    fishedible.text(datafish[i].edible);
    fishmenu.attr('datafish-id', i);

}
```

Comment: how each fish is mapped to person?

Comment: Try `var i = data[0].fishes;` This will get the id

Comment: To loop through all use `$.each(data, function(i,val){
       console.log(val.fishes);
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote you a function with wich you can get a person's fish:

```
function getFish(datafish, person) {
    var fish;
    for(var i = 0; i < datafish.length; i++) {
        if(datafish[i].id == person.fishes) {
            fish = datafish[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return fish;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a continuation of "Think Different"'s Comment, 
You have an array of Person objects, an array (ie [1,2,3]) is accessed with indices starting with 0 to no_of_elements-1 . and an object's attribute is accessed with dot notation, so you have to select a person in the array of persons for that you need to index,

For instance you need the fish of first person, the first person is to be selected
The first person is at 0th index of your data array so use

```
data[0]
```

Now you need the fish of the first person so use dot notation to get the fish attribute

```
data[0].fishes
```

This will give you the fish owned by first person
In case you need the fish of a person with a particular name do the following

```
var name="Abe"
var fishid
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
if(data[i].name==name)
{
 fishid=data[i].fishes;
 break;
}
```

Now you have the fishes id of the person named "Abe";